# How to reduce a Neo4j result to exclude nodes associated with blocked users?

Tags: neo4j

In my application, I have a list of vehicles (Cars, Trucks, Buses). Each one has a list of passengers. One of those passengers is marked as the driver. I am related to each vehicle with a passenger relationship and a ride relationship. I also have a list of "bad drivers".

I am working on writing a Cypher query that returns a list of "ride" relationships. However, I don’t want to see rides associated with the "bad drivers".

Here is a working demo: http://console.neo4j.org/r/o7q858

In this case, the "bad driver" user was the driver of `Car 2`. So my results should show ride relationships to `Car 1`, `Truck`, and `Bus`, but not `Car 2`.

I've started with a query that looks like this:

```
MATCH (u:User)<-[ride:ride]-(node)-[node_rel]->(node_user:User)
WHERE (u.name = "Me") 
  AND NOT (type(node_rel)= "passenger" AND node_rel.driver = TRUE AND node_user.name IN ["Bad Driver"])
RETURN DISTINCT ride, node
```

However, `Car 2` is still being included when it shouldn't be. What am I doing wrong, and how can I create a query that returns the correct results?

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

Does this do what you want?

```
MATCH p=(u:User)<-[ride:ride]-(node)-[node_rel]->(node_user:User)
WHERE (u.name = "Me")
WITH ride, node, COLLECT({rel: node_rel, user: node_user}) AS data
WHERE NONE (x IN data 
            WHERE exists(x.rel.driver) AND x.rel.driver AND x.user.name = "Bad Driver")
RETURN ride, node;
```

It filters out every `node` that has "Bad Driver" as a driver.

Comment: No, it needs to return Truck and Bus too.